# Vertical alignment of the first column with tabularray

Tags: vertical-alignment, tabularray

I'd like to have the question's numbers aligned with the top of each line and leave the rest centered as it is. How could I do this ?

```
\begin{tblr}{columns={valign=m},column{1} = {valign=t},colspec= 
{|ll|X[c]|X[c]|X[c]|},row{odd} = {bg=azure8},row{even} = {bg=azure9},
    row{1} = {bg=azure3, fg=white, font=\sffamily}}
\hline
\SetCell[c=2]{c} Question & & \bf Réponse A&\bf Réponse B&\bf Réponse C\\
1. & Le nombre $56$ est& un multiple de $4$&divisible par $7$&un diviseur de $8$\\
2. & La fraction $\dfrac{7}{3}$ est égale à & $7,3$ & $\dfrac{0,7}{0,3}$ & $2,333$ \\
3. & Le quotient ${13,5}\div{3,12}$ est égal à& 
$135\div{31,2}$&$135\div312$&$1350\div312$ \\
4. & {Dans une classe de $28$ élèves, $20$ sont des filles. \\ La proportion de 
garçons dans cette classe est}& $\dfrac{5}{7}$&$\dfrac{2}{7}$&$\dfrac{2}{5}$ \\
5. & {Chacun des $14$ invités a reçu un tiers de melon. \\ On a donc eu besoin de}& 
$14$ melons & $4,6$ melons &$5$ melons \\
\hline
\end{tblr}
```

Comment: `columns={valign=m},column{1} = {valign=t}` have no relevance in `tabularray` -- see the  answer below -- please revert if any problem

Comment: each column can be individually configured for horizontal as well as vertical centering by using  `Q[c,m]`  -- for only horizontal centering use `Q[c]`   -- and for vertical centering `Q[m]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the following is closer to the expcted output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{ninecolors}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tblr}{colspec= {|Q[h]X[m]|Q[c,m]|Q[c,m]|Q[c,m]|},
             row{odd} = {bg=azure8},
             row{even} = {bg=azure9},
             row{1} = {bg=azure3,fg=white, font=\sffamily\bfseries},
            }
\hline
\SetCell[c=2]{l} Question 
    & 
        &  Réponse A
            & Réponse B
                & Réponse C\\
1. 
    & Le nombre $56$ est
        & un multiple de $4$
            &divisible par $7$
                &un diviseur de $8$\\
2.\phantom{$\dfrac{7}{3}$} 
    & La fraction $\dfrac{7}{3}$ est égale à 
        & $7,3$ 
            & $\dfrac{0,7}{0,3}$ 
                & $2,333$ \\
3. 
    & Le quotient ${13,5}\div{3,12}$ est égal à
        &$135\div{31,2}$
            &$135\div312$
                &$1350\div312$ \\
4. 
    & Dans une classe de $28$ élèves, $20$ sont des filles. La proportion de garçons dans cette classe est
            & $\dfrac{5}{7}$
                &$\dfrac{2}{7}$
                    &$\dfrac{2}{5}$ \\
5. 
    & Chacun des $14$ invités a reçu un tiers de melon. On a donc eu besoin de
        &$14$ melons 
            & $4,6$ melons 
                &$5$ melons \\
\hline
\end{tblr}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
    \documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{commath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/commath

\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
\selectcolormodel{natural}
\usepackage{ninecolors}
\selectcolormodel{rgb}
\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
            % columns={valign=m},
            % column{1} = {valign=t},
            colspec= {|Q[h]llll|},
            row{odd} = {bg=azure8},
            row{even} = {bg=azure9},
            row{1} = {bg=azure3, 
            fg=white, 
            font=\sffamily}
            }
\hline
 Question 
    & 
        & \bf Réponse A
            &\bf Réponse B
                &\bf Réponse C\\
1. 
    & Le nombre $56$ est
        & un multiple de $4$
            &divisible par $7$
                &un diviseur de $8$\\
2. 
    & La fraction $\dfrac{7}{3}$ est égale à 
        & $7,3$ 
            & $\dfrac{0,7}{0,3}$ 
                & $2,333$ \\
3. 
    & Le quotient ${13,5}\div{3,12}$ est égal à
        &$135\div{31,2}$
            &$135\div312$
                &$1350\div312$ \\
4. 
    & {Dans une classe de $28$ élèves, $20$ sont des filles. \\ 
        La proportion de garçons dans cette classe est}
            & $\dfrac{5}{7}$
                &$\dfrac{2}{7}$
                    &$\dfrac{2}{5}$ \\
5. 
    & {Chacun des $14$ invités a reçu un tiers de melon. \\ 
    On a donc eu besoin de}
        &$14$ melons 
            & $4,6$ melons 
                &$5$ melons \\
\hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

**for the fractions adjust the question number by adding phantom text**

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{commath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/commath

\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
\selectcolormodel{natural}
\usepackage{ninecolors}
\selectcolormodel{rgb}
\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
            % columns={valign=m},
            % column{1} = {valign=t},
            colspec= {|Q[h]llll|},
            row{odd} = {bg=azure8},
            row{even} = {bg=azure9},
            row{1} = {bg=azure3, 
            fg=white, 
            font=\sffamily}
            }
\hline
 Question 
    & 
        & \bf Réponse A
            &\bf Réponse B
                &\bf Réponse C\\
1. 
    & Le nombre $56$ est
        & un multiple de $4$
            &divisible par $7$
                &un diviseur de $8$\\
2.\phantom{$\dfrac{7}{3}$} 
    & La fraction $\dfrac{7}{3}$ est égale à 
        & $7,3$ 
            & $\dfrac{0,7}{0,3}$ 
                & $2,333$ \\
3. 
    & Le quotient ${13,5}\div{3,12}$ est égal à
        &$135\div{31,2}$
            &$135\div312$
                &$1350\div312$ \\
4. 
    & {Dans une classe de $28$ élèves, $20$ sont des filles. \\ 
        La proportion de garçons dans cette classe est}
            & $\dfrac{5}{7}$
                &$\dfrac{2}{7}$
                    &$\dfrac{2}{5}$ \\
5. 
    & {Chacun des $14$ invités a reçu un tiers de melon. \\ 
    On a donc eu besoin de}
        &$14$ melons 
            & $4,6$ melons 
                &$5$ melons \\
\hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**centering of columns**

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{commath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/commath

\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
\selectcolormodel{natural}
\usepackage{ninecolors}
\selectcolormodel{rgb}
\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
            % columns={valign=m},
            % column{1} = {valign=t},
            colspec= {|Q[h]lQ[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]|},
            row{odd} = {bg=azure8},
            row{even} = {bg=azure9},
            row{1} = {bg=azure3, 
            fg=white, 
            font=\sffamily}
            }
\hline
 Question 
    & 
        & \bf Réponse A
            &\bf Réponse B
                &\bf Réponse C\\
1. 
    & Le nombre $56$ est
        & un multiple de $4$
            &divisible par $7$
                &un diviseur de $8$\\
2.\phantom{$\dfrac{7}{3}$} 
    & La fraction $\dfrac{7}{3}$ est égale à 
        & $7,3$ 
            & $\dfrac{0,7}{0,3}$ 
                & $2,333$ \\
3. 
    & Le quotient ${13,5}\div{3,12}$ est égal à
        &$135\div{31,2}$
            &$135\div312$
                &$1350\div312$ \\
4. 
    & {Dans une classe de $28$ élèves, $20$ sont des filles. \\ 
        La proportion de garçons dans cette classe est}
            & $\dfrac{5}{7}$
                &$\dfrac{2}{7}$
                    &$\dfrac{2}{5}$ \\
5. 
    & {Chacun des $14$ invités a reçu un tiers de melon. \\ 
    On a donc eu besoin de}
        &$14$ melons 
            & $4,6$ melons 
                &$5$ melons \\
\hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The vertical centering of other columns (and horizontal centering of answers) is lost.